SOFR swap NPV and cashflow different from BBG results using Python Quantlib
I'm using python quantlib to price a swap, but the NPV and cashflow result differently from BBG results as all the input controls the same, fixed schedule should be the same but floating cashflow is not. I have no idea abount what's wrong with it, can help figure out where I should modify?
code NPV result: -28451.35 BBG NPV result: -28449.30
code cashflow and BBG cashflows are:enter image description hereenter image description here
input and BBG NPV: enter image description here
curve data: enter image description here
Below is my python code.
import pandas as pd
import QuantLib as ql

calculation_date = ql.Date(22, 7, 2024)

ql.Settings.instance().evaluationDate = calculation_date

yts = ql.RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle()
index = ql.OvernightIndex("USD Overnight Index", 0, ql.USDCurrency(), ql.UnitedStates(ql.UnitedStates.Settlement), 
                          ql.Actual360(), yts)

swaps = {
    ql.Period("1W"): 5.34063/100,
    ql.Period("2W"): 5.34045/100,
    ql.Period("3W"): 5.34350/100,
    ql.Period("1M"): 5.34750/100,
    ql.Period("2M"): 5.34040/100,
    ql.Period("3M"): 5.28600/100,
    ql.Period("4M"): 5.24215/100,
    ql.Period("5M"): 5.20170/100,
    ql.Period("6M"): 5.14835/100,
    ql.Period("7M"): 5.09080/100,
    ql.Period("8M"): 5.04535/100,
    ql.Period("9M"): 4.98930/100,
    ql.Period("10M"): 4.93130/100,
    ql.Period("11M"): 4.88620/100,
    ql.Period("12M"): 4.83670/100,
    ql.Period("18M"): 4.51801/100,
    ql.Period("2Y"): 4.33160/100,
    ql.Period("3Y"): 4.08150/100,
    ql.Period("4Y"): 3.94900/100,
    ql.Period("5Y"): 3.87846/100,
    ql.Period("6Y"): 3.84260/100,
    ql.Period("7Y"): 3.82400/100,
    ql.Period("8Y"): 3.81550/100,
    ql.Period("9Y"): 3.81350/100,
    ql.Period("10Y"): 3.81640/100,
    ql.Period("12Y"): 3.83020/100,
    ql.Period("15Y"): 3.84900/100,
    ql.Period("20Y"): 3.83529/100,
    ql.Period("25Y"): 3.75940/100,
    ql.Period("30Y"): 3.67355/100,
    ql.Period("40Y"): 3.47606/100,
    ql.Period("50Y"): 3.26680/100
}

tenors = list(swaps.keys())
quotes = [ql.SimpleQuote(swaps[k]) for k in tenors]
handles = [ql.QuoteHandle(quote) for quote in quotes]

rate_helpers = []

for quote, tenor in zip(handles, tenors):
    helper = ql.OISRateHelper(2, tenor, quote, index)
    rate_helpers.append(helper)
    

curve = ql.PiecewiseFlatForward(calculation_date, rate_helpers, ql.Actual360())
yts.linkTo(curve)

swap = ql.MakeOIS(ql.Period('10Y'), 
                  index, 0.03736141, 
                  ql.Period('0D'), 
                  swapType=-1, 
                  nominal=10000000, 
                  effectiveDate=ql.Date(24, 10, 2024), 
                  paymentLag=2)

# Set the pricing engine
engine = ql.DiscountingSwapEngine(yts)
swap.setPricingEngine(engine)

# Calculate the original NPV
npv = swap.NPV()

print(npv)

cashflows = pd.DataFrame({
    'nominal': cf.nominal(),
    'accrualStartDate': cf.accrualStartDate().ISO(),
    'accrualEndDate': cf.accrualEndDate().ISO(),
    'rate': cf.rate(),
    'amount': cf.amount()
    } for cf in map(ql.as_coupon, swap.leg(1)))

print(cashflows)


Your number is literally the same, the negligible  difference you see is purely due to different methodologies when it comes to interpolation and associated calculation conventions (Bloomberg has richer set of choices compared to Quantlib).
